# i'm trying to run python in sublime but it's showing the error that's looks like i mentioned below

Tags: python, sublimetext3

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\suresh\\Desktop\\programsss\\he.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\suresh\Desktop\programsss]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\suresh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\suresh\AppData\Roaming\npm]
[Finished]
```

i'm trying to run python in sublime but it's showing the error that's looks like i mentioned below.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `py` is not a program that exists, which means that Python is not installed on your system. The `py` program is a helper program that the Python installer puts in place.

Comment: @OdatNurd can you please tell me how to do or send any video link to install that python helper program.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/S2cdJi_6C7g), while not covering that specifically, explains the issue in more detail. However, all you need to go is go to the [Python download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) page, download the install, and install it. There will be an option that mentions the `py` helper; it should be checked by default. Don't uncheck it and you're good.